# How to find pattern next to a given string using regex in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a string formatted for example like "segmentation_level1_id_10" and would like to extract the level number associated to it (i.e. the number directly after the word level).

I have a solution that does this in two steps, first finds the pattern `level\\d+` then replaces the level with missing after, but I would like to know if it's possible to do this in one step just with `str_extract`

Example below:

```
library(stringr)

segmentation_id <- "segmentation_level1_id_10"

segmentation_level <- str_replace(str_extract(segmentation_id, "level\\d+"), "level", "")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is by using a stringr library `str_extract` function with a regex featuring a lookbehind:

```
> library(stringr)
> s = "segmentation_level1_id_10"
> str_extract(s, "(?<=level)\\d+")
## or to make sure we match the level after _: str_extract(s, "(?<=_level)\\d+")
[1] "1"
```

Or using `str_match` that allows extracting *captured group texts*:

```
> str_match(s, "_level(\\d+)")[,2]
[1] "1"
```

It can be done with base R using the `gsub` and making use of the same capturing mechanism used in `str_match`, but also using a backreference to restore the captured text in the replacement result:

```
> gsub("^.*level(\\d+).*", "\\1", s)
[1] "1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers